# Eventbrite Auth.net Emulator

Tags: payment-processing, eventbrite

I am looking at integrating a payment processor that uses the Auth.net emulator feature - ie ability to use the Auth.net integration, but using a different URL to do the actual transactions.
See here for example: http://docs.ultracart.com/display/ucdoc/Configuring+a+Gateway+that+Supports+Authorize.Net+Emulation

Anyone managed to integrate anything other than Paypal, wallet and auth.net with EventBrite?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I work on Eventbrite's API/Platform team, so hopefully I can help you out here.

Other payment gateways are emulating Auth.net's API so that they can easily be plugged in to platforms that currently support Auth.net, but the work to integrate an additional payment gateway that has an auth.net emulator would still fall on Eventbrite (and can't independently be done by a third party).

We're not currently looking to add additional gateways, but if you have a specific request then I'd be happy to pass on the request.

You can contact us here: http://twitter.com/eventbriteapi